# Angular directive with dynamic content

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created an accordion toggle for ionic angular in [this punkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OlmIZ6?p=preview).

What i intend to achieve is to translate it to an directive that can be used as follow, where the content is dynamic based on the html that user insert. It could be a form, a text or simply a button. How could it be done??

```
<custom-accordion title="Header 1">
    Content 1
</custom-accordion>


<custom-accordion title="Header 2">
        Text: <input type="text" style="background: grey;" /><br>
        Number: <input type="number" style="background: grey;" /><br>
 </custom-accordion>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a directive for the accordion and then load the content dynamically based on a scope variable. You might have to create separate HTML files for the content that you desire. Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oR0jmFxrsMlN4b1w7n6y?p=preview) for the same.

**Directive**

```
angular.module('starter.directives', [])
.directive("dynamicAccordion", function() {
  return {
    restrict:"A/E",
    scope: {
      content: "@"
    },
    template:"<div ng-include=getContent()></div>",
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.getContent = function() {
        return scope.content;
      },
      scope.toggleContent = function() {
        scope.isShow = !scope.isShow;
      },
      scope.isShow = true;
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-view title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="has-header padding">
      <dynamic-accordion content="accordionbutton.html"></dynamic-accordion>
      <dynamic-accordion content="accordionform.html"></dynamic-accordion>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**EDIT**
This [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/veC78rspiYslgqfiA5D2?p=preview) exposes the model from each form to the controller.
**Directive**

```
angular.module('starter.directives', [])
.directive("dynamicAccordion", function() {
  return {
    restrict:"A/E",
    scope: {
      content: "@",
      model: "="
    },
    template:"<div ng-include=getContent()></div>",
    link: function(scope) {

      scope.getContent = function() {
        return scope.content;
      },
      scope.toggleContent = function() {
        scope.isShow = !scope.isShow;
      },
      scope.isShow = true;
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
      {{ form | json }}
      <dynamic-accordion content="accordionbutton.html" model="model1"></dynamic-accordion>
      <dynamic-accordion content="accordionform.html" model="model2"></dynamic-accordion>
    </form>
    <button ng-click="checkModel()">Check Model</button>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.model1 = {
        text: "Default - 1",
        number: 0
      };

      $scope.model2 = {
        text: "Default - 2",
        number: 0
      };

      $scope.checkModel = function() {
        console.log("Text_1 "+$scope.model1.text +" Number_1 "+$scope.model1.number);
        console.log("Text_2 "+$scope.model2.text +" Number_2 "+$scope.model2.number);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i am trying to wrap a form outside adn have ng-model inside the `accordionbutton` and `accordionform html` as in this new plunkr here [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/P5neLRtua9Ldf0aReeu4?p=preview). but it seems that ng-model value is not being accessible outside.

Comment: You can't directly expose the model but it can be done by 2-way binding. I have created another plunkr on top of the new plunkr you created. http://plnkr.co/edit/veC78rspiYslgqfiA5D2?p=preview. See my edit in the answer.

Comment: @vincentsty did you get what you are looking for? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation. What can i do if i do not intent to have the content inside separate html file??